# Parsing error while building images for Raspberry pi 3 using yocto

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, yocto

I am trying to build images for Raspberry pi 3 using yocto by referring [this](http://kernelhacks.com/raspberry-pi-3-with-yocto/), while running bitbake command I am getting following error.

In the error log, it says error while executing a python function, but no details about the error, I could see the exception **"Exception: TypeError: getVar() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)"**. But in the yocto many places I could see getVar is taking only two arguments.

Can you guide in fixing this issue. I could see d.getVar() many places, can you tell me what is d here, I searched in yocto documentation but didn't find any info explaining what is d.

```
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi_4.9.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was: File: '<code>', lineno: 17, function: <module>
     0013:__anon_146__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_classes_siteinfo_bbclass(d)
     0014:__anon_381__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_classes_kernel_yocto_bbclass(d)
     0015:__anon_6__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_dtb_inc(d)
     0016:__anon_148__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_rpi_inc(d)  *** 0017:__anon_39__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_raspberrypi_inc(d) File: '/home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi.inc', lineno: 38, function:
__anon_39__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_raspberrypi_inc
     0034:# See http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#anonymous-python-functions
     0035:python __anonymous () {
     0036:    kerneltype = d.getVar('KERNEL_IMAGETYPE', True)
     0037:    kerneldt = get_dts(d, d.getVar('LINUX_VERSION', True))  *** 0038:    d.setVar("KERNEL_DEVICETREE", kerneldt)
     0039:}
     0040:
     0041:do_kernel_configme_prepend() {
     0042:    install -m 0644 ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} ${WORKDIR}/defconfig || die "No default configuration for ${MACHINE} / ${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} available." File: '/home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/classes/linux-raspberrypi-base.bbclass', lineno: 6, function: get_dts
     0002:
     0003:def get_dts(d, ver=None):
     0004:    import re
     0005:  *** 0006:    staging_dir = d.getVar("STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR")
     0007:    dts = d.getVar("KERNEL_DEVICETREE")
     0008:
     0009:    # d.getVar() might return 'None' as a normal string
     0010:    # leading to 'is None' check isn't enough. Exception: TypeError: getVar() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi_4.9.bb ERROR: /home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi_4.4.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was: File: '<code>', lineno: 17, function: <module>
     0013:__anon_146__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_classes_siteinfo_bbclass(d)
     0014:__anon_381__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_classes_kernel_yocto_bbclass(d)
     0015:__anon_6__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_dtb_inc(d)
     0016:__anon_148__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_rpi_inc(d)  *** 0017:__anon_39__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_raspberrypi_inc(d) File: '/home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi.inc', lineno: 38, function:
__anon_39__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_raspberrypi_inc
     0034:# See http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#anonymous-python-functions
     0035:python __anonymous () {
     0036:    kerneltype = d.getVar('KERNEL_IMAGETYPE', True)
     0037:    kerneldt = get_dts(d, d.getVar('LINUX_VERSION', True))  *** 0038:    d.setVar("KERNEL_DEVICETREE", kerneldt)
     0039:}
     0040:
     0041:do_kernel_configme_prepend() {
     0042:    install -m 0644 ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} ${WORKDIR}/defconfig || die "No default configuration for ${MACHINE} / ${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} available." File: '/home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/classes/linux-raspberrypi-base.bbclass', lineno: 6, function: get_dts
     0002:
     0003:def get_dts(d, ver=None):
     0004:    import re
     0005:  *** 0006:    staging_dir = d.getVar("STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR")
     0007:    dts = d.getVar("KERNEL_DEVICETREE")
     0008:
     0009:    # d.getVar() might return 'None' as a normal string
     0010:    # leading to 'is None' check isn't enough. Exception: TypeError: getVar() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

ERROR: /home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi_dev.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was: File: '<code>', lineno: 17, function: <module>
     0013:__anon_146__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_classes_siteinfo_bbclass(d)
     0014:__anon_381__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_classes_kernel_yocto_bbclass(d)
     0015:__anon_6__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_poky_meta_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_dtb_inc(d)
     0016:__anon_148__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_rpi_inc(d)  *** 0017:__anon_39__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_raspberrypi_inc(d) File: '/home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi.inc', lineno: 38, function:
__anon_39__home_ubuntu_raspberryYocto_meta_raspberrypi_recipes_kernel_linux_linux_raspberrypi_inc
     0034:# See http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#anonymous-python-functions
     0035:python __anonymous () {
     0036:    kerneltype = d.getVar('KERNEL_IMAGETYPE', True)
     0037:    kerneldt = get_dts(d, d.getVar('LINUX_VERSION', True))  *** 0038:    d.setVar("KERNEL_DEVICETREE", kerneldt)
     0039:}
     0040:
     0041:do_kernel_configme_prepend() {
     0042:    install -m 0644 ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} ${WORKDIR}/defconfig || die "No default configuration for ${MACHINE} / ${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} available." File: '/home/ubuntu/raspberryYocto/meta-raspberrypi/classes/linux-raspberrypi-base.bbclass', lineno: 6, function: get_dts
     0002:
     0003:def get_dts(d, ver=None):
     0004:    import re
     0005:  *** 0006:    staging_dir = d.getVar("STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR")
     0007:    dts = d.getVar("KERNEL_DEVICETREE")
     0008:
     0009:    # d.getVar() might return 'None' as a normal string
     0010:    # leading to 'is None' check isn't enough. Exception: TypeError: getVar() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: The getVar function{getVar(var, d, exp = False)} is defined at data.py(available @ bitbake/lib/bb) which internally calling {d.getVar(var, exp)}. I have added "import data" in bb file, but it is giving parsing error at import statement. same issue when I try to add in inc file also. Can you help how to import this data.py in "meta-raspberrypi" layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced with the same issue and fixed by switching to *morty* branch on *meta-raspberrypi* layer that same as the branch of my poky environment.

Comment: Thanks for the info. it helped in fixing the issue. I have switched to krogoth branch as the poky branch is krogoth and it worked.